# Sending japanese characters over JSON

Tags: json

I tried sending japanese letters via json, however, the json value returned is `"jspString":"???????"`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

info.put("japString", "よやかなゆひま");
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("info", info.toString()));
postCard.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));   
postResponse = postCardClient.execute(postCard);
postResponseEntity = postResponse.getEntity();
String printResult = EntityUtils.toString(postResponseEntity);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer: just add toString() to `info.put("japString", "よやかなゆひま".toString());`. Internally, it escapes the unicode characters.

Answer (score -1):

just use postCard.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,  "UTF-8")) instead
hope this will help